# Querying model by ForeignKey to receive data in another ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am having trouble running a query through a table that I built as basically a linkage type table to link `Company` and `Package`

```
class CompanyPackageLink(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('business.Company', related_name='company_packages')
    package = models.ForeignKey('business.Package', related_name='packages')
```

I am trying to query the `CompanyPackage` table by `company` and then retrieve all packages associates to that query.

I have something like...

```
company = Company.objects.get(employee=self.request.user)
company_packages = CompanyPackageLink.objects.filter(company=company).select_related('package')
```

Now this returns a correct quesyset, but it returns the CompanyPackage instance.

```
<QuerySet [<CompanyPackageLink: companyA: PackageA>, <CompanyPackageLink: CompanyB: PackageB>]>
```

I would like my query to return the actual `Package` model instance where I can retrieve name, price, etc.

So I would like the returned queryset to actually return this..

```
<QuerySet [<Package: $100.00>, <Package: $200.00>]>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily query with:

```
Package.objects.filter(packages__company=company)
```

it is possible that there are two (or more) `CompanyPackageLink` with the same `Package` and `Company`. In that case the `QuerySet` will contain that `Package` multiple times. You can avoid that by using [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

```
Package.objects.filter(packages__company=company).distinct()
```

Comment: That is amazing. I had no idea. Thank you!